# R dropping NA's in logical column levels

Tags: r, logical-operators, na

I have a dataframe, which includes a corrupt row with `NA`s and `""`. I cannot remove this from the .csv file I am importing into R since Excel cannot deal with (opening) the size of the .csv document.

I do a check when I first `read.csv()` like below to remove the row with `NA`:

```
  if ( any( is.na(unique(data$A)) )   ){
  print("WARNING: data has a corrupt row in it!")  
  data <- data[ !is.na(data$A) , ]  
  }
```

However, as if it is a `factor`, the `A`column remembers `NA` as a level:

```
> summary(data$A)
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical  185692   36978       0
```

This obviously causes issues when I am trying to fit a linear model. How can I get rid of the NA as a logical level here?

I tried this but doesn't seem to work:

```
A <- as.logical(droplevels(factor(data_combine$A)))
summary(A)
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical  185692   36978       0 
unique(A)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Hmm, if I run `x <- factor(c(LETTERS[1:3], NA)`, the factor levels of x don't include NA, even after running `levels(x) <- c(levels(x), NA)`

Comment: The `summary(data$A)` appears to show that `data$A` is in fact a `logical` and not a `factor`. Check `summary(c(T,F))` and `summary(factor(c(T,F)))`.

Comment: @beginneR - you can add NA as a level with `factor(NA, exclude=NULL)`

Comment: Looks like the NAs show up in a logical vector summary always.  Try `summary(c(logical(4), !logical(2)))`

Comment: @Richard Scriven, yes I did notice that just now. So maybe there is not a `level` related problem (introduced by `NA`) here.

Comment: It would really help if you gave us a sample of the problem data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `data$A` is not a factor, it's a logical.  The `summary` print methods are not the same for factors and logicals.  Logicals use `summary.default` while factors dispatch to `summary.factor`.  Plus it tells you in the result that the variable is a logical.

```
fac <- factor(c(NA, letters[1:4]))
log <- c(NA, logical(4), !logical(2))
summary(fac)
#   a    b    c    d NA's 
#   1    1    1    1    1 
summary(log)
#    Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
# logical       4       2       1
```

See `?summary` for the differences.

Second, your call

```
A <- as.logical(droplevels(factor(data_combine$A)))
summary(A)
```

is also calling `summary.default` because you wrapped `droplevels` with `as.logical` (why?).  So don't change `data_combine$A` at all, and just try

```
summary(data_combine$A)
```

and see how that goes.  For more information, please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware the column is a logical. The information I was missing was that `summary(logical)` always prints `NA`'s. So it was a red herring.

Comment: @Zhubarb - I also posted another answer earlier (currently deleted) that shows how you can add an option to the summary print method.  I can undelete it if you'd like

Comment: Thanks, It would be useful to append it to your existing one if it is not going to be a hassle.

Comment: @Zhubarb - I undeleted my other answer because it's a bit long to append to this one

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my other answer, those actually are not factor levels.  Since you asked how to remove the NA printing on `summary`, I'm undeleting this answer.

The `NA` printing is hard-coded into a summary for a logical vector.  Here's the relevant code from `summary.default`.

```
# value <- if (is.logical(object)) 
#     c(Mode = "logical", {
#         tb <- table(object, exclude = NULL)
#         if (!is.null(n <- dimnames(tb)[[1L]]) && any(iN <- is.na(n))) 
#             dimnames(tb)[[1L]][iN] <- "NA's"
#         tb
#     })
```

The `exclude = NULL` in `table` is the problem. If we look at the `exclude` argument in `table` with a logical vector `log`, we can see that when it is `NULL` the NAs always print out.

```
log <- c(NA, logical(4), NA, !logical(2), NA)
table(log, exclude = NULL)                  ## with NA values
# log
# FALSE  TRUE  <NA> 
#     4     2     3 
table(log[!is.na(log)], exclude = NULL)     ## NA values removed
# 
# FALSE  TRUE  <NA> 
#     4     2     0
```

To make your summary print the way you want it, we can write a `summary` method based on the original source code.

```
summary.logvec <- function(object, exclude = NA) {
    stopifnot(is.logical(object))
    value <- c(Mode = "logical", {
        tb <- table(object, exclude = exclude)
            if(is.null(exclude)) {
                if (!is.null(n <- dimnames(tb)[[1L]]) && any(iN <- is.na(n)))
                    dimnames(tb)[[1L]][iN] <- "NA's"
            }
            tb
        })
    class(value) <- c("summaryDefault", "table")
    print.summary.logvec <- function(x) {
        UseMethod("print.summaryDefault")
    } 
    value
}
```

And then here are the results.  Since we set `exclude = NA` in our print method the NAs will not print unless we set it to NULL

```
summary(log)  ## original vector
#    Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
# logical       4       2       3 
class(log) <- "logvec"
summary(log, exclude = NULL)  ## prints NA when exclude = NULL
#    Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
# logical       4       2       3 
summary(log)  ## NA's don't print 
#    Mode   FALSE    TRUE 
# logical       4       2
```

Now that I've done all this I'm wondering if you have tried to run your linear model.